# Trying to send back error json from Servlet filter instead of allowing the request to go through

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, filter

I have implemented a Filter for a servlet(java). But there is a condition that  in some cases i should not be allowing the request to go through( chain.doFilter() ) and allow access to Servlet.

Instead i need to send Error json object back to browser form filter itself. Please let me know how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `Filter` has access to the `ServletResponse`. Simply get its `OutputStream` and use it to write the JSON content. (And don't follow the chain.)

Comment: THanks. Silly mistake on my side to not understand this.